# Remove part of video only using command line (probably FFMPEG)

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a 4 hour long .mp4 file and when I upload it to Youtube the entire audio track gets muted because of 30 seconds of some song between 01:21:47 and 01:22:24, how can I remove JUST this part of the video, or even better - just THIS part of the audio from the video?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are sure it's just that portion of the audio, then you can just mute it:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -af volume=0:enable='between(t,01:21:47,01:22:24)' -c:v copy output.mp4
```

Depending on your shell, you may have to escape the colons in the timecodes, or maybe switch to seconds representation (01:21:47 = 4907, 01:22:24 = 4944).

Comment: Hey thanks but here's what I came up with ffmpeg -i 88595331.mp4 -af volume=0:enable='between(t,4907,4944)' -c:v copy 88595331_v2.mp4 and the error http://i.imgur.com/aUogYcQ.png

Comment: Try `'between(t\,4907\,4944)'`

Comment: Instead of doing this right now, first I suggest uploading just a trimmed portion and testing: `ffmpeg -ss 01:21:47 -t 38 input.mp4 test.mp4`

Comment: In my case I need to add double quotes to stop error, e.g. `-af "volume=0:enable='between(t,963,965)'"`, ref: https://lists.ffmpeg.org/pipermail/ffmpeg-user/2014-January/019192.html . I also need to use "second" in my case.

Comment: And the format of mute multiple portion is like that: `"volume=0:enable='between(t,1820,1821)', volume=0:enable='between(t,2216,2217)'"` , ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29222419/1074998

Comment: @林果皞 You can just use `volume=0:enable='between(t,1820,1821)+between(t,2216,2217)'`

Comment: for some one to convert to seconds use this command
echo "00:04:34" | awk -F: '{ print ($1 * 3600) + ($2 * 60) + $3 }'

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me (courtesy of Manny Morales —a slack friend):

You need three operations done separately.

Say you got a 20 sec video, and you want to remove 5 sec part between 10 sec to 15 sec.

You do this:

01.

```
ffmpeg -ss 00:00:00 -to 00:10:00 -i input.mp4 -c copy 01.mp4
```

2. 

```
ffmpeg -ss 00:00:15 -to 00:00:20 -i input.mp4 -c copy 02.mp4
```

3. 

```
echo file 01.mp4 > list.txt
echo file 02.mp4 >> list.txt
ffmpeg -f concat -i list.txt -c copy output.mp4
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with an FFmpeg filtergraph.

Try something along these lines:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -filter_complex '[0:v] trim=end=01:21:47 [v1], [0:a] atrim=end=01:21:47 [a1], [0:v] trim=start=01:22:24 [v2], [0:a] atrim=start=01:22:24 [a2], [v1][a1][v2][a2] concat=n=2:v=1:a=1 [v][a]' -map '[v]' -map '[a]' output.mp4
```

This particular filtergraph slices the input into four pieces: the initial video segment, the initial audio segment, the final video segment, and the final audio segment. Then it concatenates the video and audio segments together.

See https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html for more details on filtering.

Comment: Apart from the merits of re-encoding 4 hours of video just to mute a 30 second audio segment, this won't give the desired result because the concat filter requires all segments to have starting timestamps be `0`. But the trim filters don't reset timestamps, so `v2` and `a2` will have non-zero timestamps and the concat filter won't behave predictably.