# How to set lowpass filter in specific range with ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a .m4a music file, it has noise part around 57th second, and I want to set lowpass in this specific range only instead of entire audio file.

I learned `between()` syntax at 
[Remove part of video only using command line (probably FFMPEG)](https://superuser.com/a/1123173/248836), e.g. `-af "volume=0:enable='between(t,55,58)'"` is working, but it seems error if I do `-af "lowpass=3000:enable='between(t,55,58)'"`:

```
$ ffmpeg -i test.m4a -af "lowpass=3000:enable='between(t,55,58)'" test_3000.m4a 
ffmpeg version 3.4.6-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 7 (Ubuntu 7.3.0-16ubuntu3)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0ubuntu0.18.04.1 --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librubberband --enable-librsvg --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libopencv --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
  WARNING: library configuration mismatch
  avcodec     configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0ubuntu0.18.04.1 --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librubberband --enable-librsvg --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libopencv --enable-libx264 --enable-shared --enable-version3 --disable-doc --disable-programs --enable-libopencore_amrnb --enable-libopencore_amrwb --enable-libtesseract --enable-libvo_amrwbenc
  libavutil      55. 78.100 / 55. 78.100
  libavcodec     57.107.100 / 57.107.100
  libavformat    57. 83.100 / 57. 83.100
  libavdevice    57. 10.100 / 57. 10.100
  libavfilter     6.107.100 /  6.107.100
  libavresample   3.  7.  0 /  3.  7.  0
  libswscale      4.  8.100 /  4.  8.100
  libswresample   2.  9.100 /  2.  9.100
  libpostproc    54.  7.100 / 54.  7.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'test.m4a':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2mp41
    title           : 10219424412459984
    encoder         : Lavf57.83.100
  Duration: 00:01:10.94, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 64 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Audio: aac (HE-AAC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 64 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (aac (native) -> aac (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[Parsed_lowpass_0 @ 0x55eab39197a0] Timeline ('enable' option) not supported with filter 'lowpass'
[AVFilterGraph @ 0x55eab391e5c0] Error initializing filter 'lowpass' with args '3000:enable=between(t,55,58)'
Error reinitializing filters!
Failed to inject frame into filter network: Not yet implemented in FFmpeg, patches welcome
Error while processing the decoded data for stream #0:0
Conversion failed!
$
```

How to set lowpass filter in specific range and multiple specfic range?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upgrade ffmpeg to recent git build (> 1 May 2019). Timeline support has been added.

Answer (score 0):

As the accepted answer suggested, I need to get the latest git, but how do I build it in my Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS ?

I don't have much experience of `make`, I just done build the ffmpeg and want to share how I do it.

After git clone the source, the first thing I do is trying to mimic current configuration options of my Ubuntu current ffmpeg, I can see the options by running `ffmpeg -v`:

```
xb@dnxb:~/Downloads/ffmpeg$ ffmpeg -v
ffmpeg version 3.4.6-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 7 (Ubuntu 7.3.0-16ubuntu3)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0ubuntu0.18.04.1 --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librubberband --enable-librsvg --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libopencv --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
  WARNING: library configuration mismatch
  avcodec     configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0ubuntu0.18.04.1 --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librubberband --enable-librsvg --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libopencv --enable-libx264 --enable-shared --enable-version3 --disable-doc --disable-programs --enable-libopencore_amrnb --enable-libopencore_amrwb --enable-libtesseract --enable-libvo_amrwbenc
...
```

Remove the duplicated --"options", then try to `./configure --"options above"` will get error similar to:

```
ERROR: libwebp >= 0.2.0 not found using pkg-config
```

I need to do `apt-cache search libwebp` to search the development package:

```
xb@dnxb:~/Downloads/ffmpeg$ apt-cache search libwebp
libwebp-dev - Lossy compression of digital photographic images.
libwebp6 - Lossy compression of digital photographic images.
libwebpdemux2 - Lossy compression of digital photographic images.
libwebpmux3 - Lossy compression of digital photographic images.
xb@dnxb:~/Downloads/ffmpeg/testtest/ffmpeg
```

The development usually end with `-dev`, then run `sudo apt install libwebp-dev` to fix this error. Repeat the steps (spent a lot of time becauses of a lot of options) to fixed all the missing development package errors.

But I still I get unresolved error with some options, so need to remove the following options, which the options name can inspired from error message:

```
--enable-libcdio --enable-libflite --enable-libiec61883 --enable-libopencv --enable-libmysofa
```

I failed to build opencv, I give up and disable this option.

But I still get `v4l2` and `v4l2m2m` erros when `make`. I need to do `./configure --help` and repeat the step to check output of `./configure --"optinos"` to ensures no `v4l2` and `v4l2m2m` appear on the output.

Eventually I figure out I can use `--disable-v4l2-m2m`(I direct get this name from `--help`), `--disable-encoder=<list of encoder names get from ./configure section 'encoder' output which contains v4l2m2m>`, `--disable-decoder=<list of decoder names get from ./configure section 'decoder' output which contains v4l2m2m>`, `--disable-indev=<indev section has v4l2>`, `--disable-outdev=<outdev section has v4l2>`, and come out with this working ./configure command options:

```
./configure --disable-v4l2-m2m --extra-version=0ubuntu0.18.04.1 --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu \
--incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu  --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth \
--enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libfontconfig \
--enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopenjpeg \
--enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librubberband --enable-librsvg --enable-libshine \
--enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis \
--enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq \
--enable-libzvbi --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm \
--enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-shared --enable-version3 --enable-doc --enable-libopencore_amrnb \
--enable-libopencore_amrwb --enable-libtesseract --enable-debug \
--disable-encoder=h264_v4l2m2m,vp8_v4l2m2m,vc1_v4l2m2m,vp9_v4l2m2m,mpeg4_v4l2m2m,mpeg2_v4l2m2m,mpeg1_v4l2m2m,h264_v4l2m2m,h263_v4l2m2m \
--disable-decoder=h263_v4l2m2m,h264_v4l2m2m,mpeg1_v4l2m2m,mpeg2_v4l2m2m,mpeg4_v4l2m2m,vp9_v4l2m2m,vc1_v4l2m2m,vp8_v4l2m2m \
--disable-indev=v4l2 --disable-outdev=v4l2 --disable-v4l2-m2m
```

Run with `make -j7` and it able to build successfully,

```
xb@dnxb:~/Downloads/ffmpeg$ ./ffmpeg -i ../test.m4a -af "lowpass=3000:enable='between(t,55,58)'" test_3000.m4a
./ffmpeg: error while loading shared libraries: libavdevice.so.58: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
xb@dnxb:~/Downloads/ffmpeg$
```

My ubuntu only has libavdevice.so.57, while libavdevice.so.58 is inside my build directory, so I need set the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=` to dismiss that erros (the directory name can inspired by error, e.g `libavdevice.so.58` means `libavdevice/`), I set my current path as `P` variable:

```
 P=~/Downloads/ffmpeg/; LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$P"/libavdevice/:\
"$P"/libavfilter/:"$P"/libavformat/:"$P"/libavcodec/:\
"$P"/libavresample:$P/libpostproc/:$P/libswresample/:$P/libswscale/:$P/libavutil/ \
./ffmpeg -i test.m4a -af "lowpass=3000:enable='between(t,55,58)'" test_3000.m4a
```

It able to convert .m4a successfully. I compare the `-filters` between original ffmpeg and my build ffmpeg, and confirms the filters has been changed:

```
xb@dnxb:~/Downloads/ffmpeg$ ffmpeg -filters |& grep -n pass
39: ... allpass           A->A       Apply a two-pole all-pass filter.
53: ... aselect           A->N       Select audio frames to pass in output.
67: ... bandpass          A->A       Apply a two-pole Butterworth band-pass filter.
90: ... highpass          A->A       Apply a high-pass filter with 3dB point frequency.
94: ... lowpass           A->A       Apply a low-pass filter with 3dB point frequency.
267: ... select            V->N       Select video frames to pass in output.
xb@dnxb:~/Downloads/ffmpeg$ P=~/Downloads/ffmpeg/; LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$P"/libavdevice/:"$P"/libavfilter/:"$P"/libavformat/:"$P"/libavcodec/:"$P"/libavresample:$P/libpostproc/:$P/libswresample/:$P/libswscale/:$P/libavutil/ ./ffmpeg -filters |& grep -n pass
46: TSC allpass           A->A       Apply a two-pole all-pass filter.
62: ... aselect           A->N       Select audio frames to pass in output.
77: TSC bandpass          A->A       Apply a two-pole Butterworth band-pass filter.
101: TSC highpass          A->A       Apply a high-pass filter with 3dB point frequency.
106: TSC lowpass           A->A       Apply a low-pass filter with 3dB point frequency.
130: ... sinc              |->A       Generate a sinc kaiser-windowed low-pass, high-pass, band-pass, or band-reject FIR coefficients.
305: ... select            V->N       Select video frames to pass in output.
xb@dnxb:~/Downloads/ffmpeg$
```

Definition of this filters:

```
xb@dnxb:~/Downloads/ffmpeg$ ffmpeg -filters |& grep -n Filters -A 7
15:Filters:
16-  T.. = Timeline support
17-  .S. = Slice threading
18-  ..C = Command support
19-  A = Audio input/output
20-  V = Video input/output
21-  N = Dynamic number and/or type of input/output
22-  | = Source or sink filter
xb@dnxb:~/Downloads/ffmpeg$
```

As you can see, lowpass and highpass shows `TSC` which `T` means Timeline support.